# How to remove repeating strings from a list (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I have extracted a list of words from a paragraph of text but I want to remove repeating words from that list. How can I do it?

My output:

['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'is', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'sun', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']

Desired output:

['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']

Comment: `set()` is good for this purpose

Comment: Jussi's answer is correct. easiest way

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) At the very least, you're expected to do a quick web search before asking. Please also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre] showing your attempt. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to remove list duplicates by **extracting the same keys of the every list**, a dict object function called `"fromkeys"` this function removes duplicated elements:

```
test_list = ['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'is', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'sun', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
test_list = list(dict.fromkeys(test_list))
print(test_list)
```

Another way is that you can iterate the list over a for loop:

```
res = list()
for item in test_list:
    if item not in res:
        res.append(item)
```

A more concise version of the last approach could be as the following:

```
res = list()
[res.append(item) for item in test_list if item not in res]
```

Whole output:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

[Jussi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6075996/jussi-nurminen) answer is also true, the `set` also removes list duplicates:

```
test_list = list(set(test_list))
```

Comment: thanks, i prefer the iteration one. It is easier to understand for me :)

Comment: @AymanMostafa the iteration one is the worst of all three because it is O(n^2) and the others are all O(n)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi could you elaborate why it is the worst?

Comment: @AymanMostafa Looking for an item in a list is O(n), where n is the number of items in the list. Doing that n times makes that line O(n^2). For sets and dicts, lookup is O(1). Doing that n times makes it O(n). If you double the size of your input, your selected approach will take ~four times longer, but the others will only be ~2x. Look up time complexity

Comment: despite the application complexity, what @PranavHosangadi is saying is correct, the execution time should always be considered.

here's a code that proves the time difference between the codes

https://github.com/ramymagdy-rm/py_playground/blob/main/remove_repeating_elements_from_list_timeit.py

the time differences are:
0.015302300000000005
0.0850022
0.09027770000000002
0.011084099999999986 sec
respectively. THE FIRST AND LAST APPROACHES ARE THE QUICKEST.

Please notice that the one line for loop approach has been modified to a correct syntax